# AWS S3 credential/certificate error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Im totally new to AWS. Im trying to use the AWS S3 notification API's. Im receiving the following error.

com.amazonaws.services.sns.model.AmazonSNSException: The security token included in the request is invalid. (Service: AmazonSNS; Status Code: 403; Error Code: InvalidClientTokenId; ...

I have NO idea what's wrong. For my accessID and secretID. Im using the main AWS codes for authentication. Am I supposed to use the main AWS credentials, or something else. Im not using any type of certificate. I dont know if they are even required.

Im using the example code supplied by AWS with some modifications to read a property file instead of hard coding the accessID and secretID.

Can someone please steer me in the right direction? I am completely confused.

```
public class AmazonSNSReceiver {
     // AWS credentials -- replace with your credentials
    static String ACCESS_KEY;
    static String SECRET_KEY;

    // Shared queue for notifications from HTTP server
    static BlockingQueue<Map<String, String>> messageQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<Map<String, String>>();

    // Receiver loop
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        AmazonSNSReceiver sns = new AmazonSNSReceiver();

        sns.getPropertyValues();
        if (args.length == 1) {
        sns.SNSClient(args[0]);
            } else {
                sns.SNSClient("8989");
        }
    }
        // Create a client
        public void SNSClient(String thisport) throws Exception{

        AmazonSNSClient service = new AmazonSNSClient(new BasicAWSCredentials(ACCESS_KEY, SECRET_KEY));

        // Create a topic
        CreateTopicRequest createReq = new CreateTopicRequest().withName("MyTopic");
        CreateTopicResult createRes = service.createTopic(createReq);

        // Get an HTTP Port
        int port = thisport == null ? 8989 : Integer.parseInt(thisport);

        // Create and start HTTP server
        Server server = new Server(port);
        server.setHandler(new AmazonSNSHandler());
        server.start();

        // Subscribe to topic
        SubscribeRequest subscribeReq = new SubscribeRequest()
            .withTopicArn(createRes.getTopicArn())
            .withProtocol("http")
            .withEndpoint("http://" + InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress() + ":" + port);
        service.subscribe(subscribeReq);

        for (;;) {

            // Wait for a message from HTTP server
            Map<String, String> messageMap = messageQueue.take();

            // Look for a subscription confirmation Token
            String token = messageMap.get("Token");
            if (token != null) {

                // Confirm subscription
                ConfirmSubscriptionRequest confirmReq = new ConfirmSubscriptionRequest()
                    .withTopicArn(createRes.getTopicArn())
                    .withToken(token);
                service.confirmSubscription(confirmReq);

                continue;
            }

            // Check for a notification
            String message = messageMap.get("Message");
            if (message != null) {
                System.out.println("Received message: " + message);
            }

        }

    }

    public void getPropertyValues() throws IOException {

        Properties prop = new Properties();

        InputStream properties = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("SNS.properties");

        prop.load(properties);

        ACCESS_KEY = prop.getProperty("ACCESS_KEY");
        SECRET_KEY = prop.getProperty("SECRET_KEY");

    }

    // HTTP handler
    static class AmazonSNSHandler extends AbstractHandler {

        // Handle HTTP request
        public void handle(String target, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, int dispatch) throws IOException {

            // Scan request into a string
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(request.getInputStream());
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                sb.append(scanner.nextLine());
            }

            // Build a message map from the JSON encoded message
            InputStream bytes = new ByteArrayInputStream(sb.toString().getBytes());
            Map<String, String> messageMap = new ObjectMapper().readValue(bytes, Map.class);

            // Enqueue message map for receive loop
            messageQueue.add(messageMap);

            // Set HTTP response
            response.setContentType("text/html");
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
            ((Request) request).setHandled(true);
        }        
    }
}
```

Comment: I was using the wrong credentials. But Im getting the error message:Exception in thread "main" com.amazonaws.services.sns.model.AuthorizationErrorException: Not authorized to subscribe internal endpoints (Service: AmazonSNS; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AuthorizationError; How do I subscribe to internal endpoints? Im trying to use the console, but there isnt anyplace for that.

Comment: The nature of your question has changed substantially with this comment. You can't do this: `InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress() + ":" + port);` That's returning a private ("internal endpoint") IP address.  SNS will only deliver to Internet-accessible endpoints.  SNS is inside AWS but it is outside of your VPC, so it accesses you from outside.

Answer (score 0):

Your application needs to provide AWS credentials. These credentials can be obtained by several methods:

- Create an **IAM User** and generate an Access Key and Secret Key. Include the credentials in a [configuration file](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/credentials.html) (it is not a good idea to put them in your application, since they could accidentally be published elsewhere).
- If running the code on an Amazon EC2 instance, create an **IAM Role** and assign the role to the instance when it is launched. Credentials will then be automatically provided to applications running on that instance.

It is also necessary to [**assign permissions**](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_permissions.html) to the IAM User/Role. These permissions grant the right to call various AWS API calls. The fact that you receive an `AuthorizationError` suggests that the credentials in use do not have sufficient permissions.

See: [Managing Access to Your Amazon SNS Topics](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/AccessPolicyLanguage.html)